# extracting clock seconds from yearmonth formatted string in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to extract the clock time in Tcl for a string that is formatted as YearMonth like this.  "202001" for January 2020.

```
% set value "202001" 
% set clocktime [clock scan $value -format "%Y%m"]
1608537600
```

You can see that Tcl extracts the epoch time as 1608537600

This isn't correct, as you can see.  If I convert that value back to the string value, it comes back as December 2020

```
% clock format 1608537600 -format "%Y%m"
202012
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is specified in the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm#M25) (essentially the part that says "The date is determined according to the fields that are present in the preprocessed format string. In order of preference: ...") that if a date is not specified, then the date will be taken as the current date.

Since the date is missing from the clock value provided, clock scan will return the date the script is run as the date. You can try running it with the value `2019` and you will get the same results provided you do it on the same day.

What you could do to avoid that would be to add the date. Appending `01` to the value and `%d` to the format string shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should read the documentation more carefully.  I've done this in other languages that don't seem to have this limitation, so I didn't expect Tcl to have this limitation.

Comment: @Jonjilla yea I was a bit surprised too. It feels strangely specific. I realised what was happening when I tried changing the year but it always gave me the same result while yours was different, that's when I formatted the result to include the date and it was all today's date.